# Cannot get moodle to install on my remote server/virtual machine

Tags: php, azure, virtual-machine, moodle, ubuntu-20.04

I'm playing with a free MS Azure account, and am trying to upload an open-source LMS (Learning Management System) called Moodle onto it. I've set up the virtual machine/SSH, am in the server via Windows Terminal, and have installed LAMP. I've installed Apache2, mySQL and PHP & PHP (cli version).

This is my first real play with PHP. I've managed to get the public IP to display the Apache2 Ubuntu default page (index.html inside /var/www/html/).

I've been following [this moodle installation guide](https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Installation_quick_guide#Getting_Moodle) and am stuck at the 'Install Moodle' part. I've got/decompressed moodle successfully, created the database etc. I've used **ls** and **dir -a** commands to confirm the file (I think) I need to execute is at */moodle/admin/cli/install.php* but when I try to run the php install script, all I get is 'Could not open input file: path to file here'

I've tried a few variations as below:

/usr/bin/php /moodle/admin/cli/install.php
/usr/bin/php7.4 /moodle/admin/cli/install.php

I think I'm literally at the last hurdle! Any ideas, anyone? Also, once that's done, how would I redirect the launch page from the default ubuntu index.html to the moodle startup page, or would that be automatic (following successful install?)

It's a linux/ubuntu 20.04 server.

Thanks so much kind soul.

Comment: Have you got a `config.php` file in the moodle directory? There is a sample file called `config-dist.php` in the moodle directory

Answer (score 0):

I figured out part of the issue...

I SSH'd into my virtual machine using Terminal app, used the `mv` command to move the Moodle directory into the `/var/www/html/` directory (so it was accessible via internet). I know for security reasons this isn't sensible, but for my first test ever I think it'll be fine as it's all being deleted soon!

Then, I made sure the web server/Moodle installer had the necessary read/write permissions to edit files inside that folder directory and all subfiles by doing `sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/html/moodle` and that at least let me get to the next page of the installer! I had issues with mySQL databases also not having read/write permissions but that's for another post...!